# Pycharm ImportError when running print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running Pycharm and attempting to run a simple print function:

```
print("hello")
```

and receiving an ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.pydev_rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_rpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.pydev_server import TSingleThreadedServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.server import TServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.transport import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .sslsocket import TSSLSocket, TSSLServerSocket  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\sslsocket.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Users\heath\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm not really sure what's happening--I'm not importing any libraries or anything that should result in an error to my knowledge; I just installed Pycharm and Python. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Honestly, it looks like the IDE just had a wonky installation or something. I'd restart it. If that doesn't work, try `File-> Invalidate Caches` and restart. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling.

Comment: Probably some error in Jetbrains trying to find the defined interpreter, more of a setting related issue rather than the coding.

Comment: Uninstall + reinstall worked, thanks so much!